# Is there some search engine SDK or API that I can use for local search?

Tags: gwt, search-engine, bing-api, google-local-search

I have many documents located on my disk and I want to build a search engine to search through them.
I know Google Desktop Search or Bing Desktop Search could do that. But I want to know if there's some SDK/API to do that so I can do some customization.

What I want to achieve, is that I can provide a document and the *local search engine* will return all the documents similar to it.

Answer (score 1):

In general there are [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) that can help to solve search related needs in Java (I guess you are using Java based on the tag GWT).

But I don't know how to do a search by example with these tools. I think you have to extract the relevant information of the document to construct a search based on it.